# Find own question with outscored accepted answer

Tags: discussion

I'd be interested to batch look-up through my questions and see if there is accepted answer which was outscored by other answer, and probably a span between ratings of those two questions (accepted and best rated).

Is there any possible tool we could use?

---

Final batch I've used is:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT
  q.Id As [Post Link],
  Max(a.Score) AS [Acc. score],
  Max(b.Score) AS [Top. score],
  Count(*) AS [# outscoring],
  Max(a.CreationDate) AS [Accepted answer date],
  Max(b.CreationDate) AS [Top answer date]
FROM Posts q, Posts a, Posts b
WHERE q.OwnerUserId = @UserId
  AND q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
  AND b.ParentId = q.Id
  AND b.Score > a.Score
GROUP BY q.Id
ORDER BY Max(b.Score) DESC
```

Present at: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/148346/own-outscored-accepted-answers

Comment: Yes, you could use SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer).

Comment: Write your own query for this on http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, found already present query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59542/outscored-accepted-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stack Exchange Data Explorer (aka SEDE) for this. A quick search shows me this query: [Outscored Accepted Answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59542/outscored-accepted-answers)

It currently searches through all the questions on a specific site but you could use this as a starting point and tweak it to achieve what you want.